# how to see if we got NACK or ACK in I2C efr32fg14

Tags: embedded

I need to see if the slave device sends back ACK or NACK in I2C communicaton.in page 515 of the manual bellow i see the I2C_IF register.
bitfield 11 is bushold and it says if the slave holds the line.
How to know if we got ACK or NACK from the slave?
Thanks.

https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/reference-manuals/efr32xg14-rm.pdf

[image]

Comment: Might bits 6 or 7 have anything to do with it?

Comment: Bushold is putting SDA to zero which is exactly as ACK or NACK
in what case bus hold equals ack or nack?
Thanks